# NSDocumentController newDocument:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to override newDocument: in my Cocoa Document Based Application. I have a standard project where when New is clicked in the menu bar, the First Responder receives the action. My goal is to have a window appear with new document configurations when New is clicked in the menu bar (sort of like Photoshop). After reading the Apple Docs, I have found that I need to override newDocument: in a NSDocumentController subclass. I then set that a configuration window should appear when newDocument: is called.

What is the best way to use my NSDocumentContoller subclass? I could drag an object out in Interface Builder and connect the method to the MainMenu bar, but I'm not sure that is good practice. How should I use my NSDocumentController as the new first responder for my MenuBar?

Answer (score 6):

The NSDocumentController is a singleton and you must access to your subclass **always** using the method `[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController]` to agree with this point you should

- In maimenu.xib drag an NSObject and point the Custom Class to your NSDocumentController subclass, this is necessary because the Cocoa ecosystem creates the singleton **before** any other class

Then you can override your `- (IBAction)newDocument:(id)sender` and do what you prefer.

It's a bit old but I found very useful the [Seashore](http://sourceforge.net/projects/seashore/files/) source code when I needed to subclass NSDocumentController

The image below shows the elements in XCode
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I needed to do exactly this (override `newDocument:`) and your instructions work great.